# Crafting a Comparator object for sorting generic List<? extends T> using Collections.sort()

Tags: java, generics, sorting, comparator, bounded-wildcard

I am trying to implement a generic sort utility method for a List of objects of any class that implements MyInterface. Per Java API (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), Collections.sort() method signature is:

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

I am not sure if List with a wildcard parameter can substitute a "plain" parametrized List, but I tried:

```
static void mySort(List<? extends MyInterface> myList, SortCriteria mySortCriteria) {
    Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<? super MyInterface>() {
        ...
    });
}
```

and got a compile time error,

```
The type new Comparator(){} cannot extend or implement Comparator<? super MyInterface>
A supertype may not specify any wildcard.
```

So, I changed it to:

```
static void mySort(List<? extends MyInterface> myList, SortCriteria mySortCriteria) {
    Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<MyInterface>() {
        ...
    });
}
```

And it compiles and works. Any good explanations?

Comment: When you say *"when I tried it"*, what exactly did you try? Can you post some code

Answer (score 2):

You're using *contravariance* here.

Basically, you need to have a comparator which can compare any two items in the list. If the list is of type `T`, that means that it has to be able to compare any two items of type T - but if it can compare any two items of some type X where T is a subclass of X, then that's okay too.

To give my favourite example, if you have a comparator which can compare any two shapes by area, then you could clearly use that to compare any two triangles - so it's okay to sort a `List<Triangle>` using an `AreaShapeComparator`.

I'm not sure what you mean by "when I tried it" in your last paragraph... if you could give a short but complete example which doesn't work, we can try to explain why.

EDIT: Okay, you can't use `? extends X` or `? extends Y` within a `new` expression - you can only use them as part of a declaration, either of a method, a type or a variable. When you construct a *new* object, you need to specify the exact type.

Comment: @Eugene: You need to show *exactly* what you tried - not just a single snippet out of a line, but the whole context.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand the effect of this constraint on Comparator

The constraint says that the comparator must be able to compare at the least the generic type of the `List`, *or supertypes of it*. For example, it would be valid to use a `Comaparator<Number>` to sort a `List<Integer>`. If the `Comparator` is able to compare `Number`s, then it is, of course, able to compare `Integer`s.