# Can't pass wildcard Comparator to function

Tags: java, comparator

I have the following `sort` method in a clone of `ArrayList`:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c){
    if(c == null){
        // Use ascending order (only works if types are comparable)
        class ascComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
            public int compare(T a, T b) {
                // This will raise an exception if the types are not comparable
                return ((Comparable)a).compareTo(b);
            }
        }
        c = new ascComparator<E>();
    }
    // Cast the internal array to comparable then call merge sort
    sorter.mergeSort((Comparable[])array, c);
}
```

The `sorter` object is an instance of `Sort`:

```
public class Sort {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <E extends Comparable<E>> E[] mergeSort(E[] list, Comparator<? super E> c){
        ...
    }
}
```

I get the following error on the `sorter.mergeSort` line:

```
The method mergeSort(E[], Comparator<? super E>) in the type Sort is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable[], Comparator<capture#8-of ? super E>)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening  as both the parameter and argument have type `Comparator<? super E>`.

Comment: Does `E extends Comparable<E>` from the signature of `mergeSort` do something well-defined?

Comment: I use a `Comparator` to compare items in `mergeSort`. Is it not required?

Comment: @gkhaos [The meaning of <T extends Comparable<T>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537500/java-the-meaning-of-t-extends-comparablet)

Comment: There is no reason to do _anything_ with `Comparable` except when creating `ascComparator`.  There should be no other mention of `Comparable` in your code.  I recommend starting there.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/1540223/139985 for an explanation of why the `c` parameter is declared as `Comparator<? super E> c` rather than `Comparator<? extends E> c` in `List.sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their comments. I've now fixed it.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c){
    if(c == null){
        // Use ascending order (only works if types are comparable)
        class ascComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
            public int compare(T a, T b) {
                // This will raise an exception if the types are not comparable
                return ((Comparable<T>)a).compareTo(b);
            }
        }
        c = new ascComparator<E>();
    }
    // Cast the internal array to E then call merge sort
    sorter.sort((E[]) array, c);
}
```

As Kayaman said, I shouldn't use `rawtypes` so I've given `ascComparator` parameter `T`. I've also casted `array` to `E` instead of `Comparable` as it didn't do what I thought it did. I've also changed `Sort`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <E> E[] mergeSort(E[] list, Comparator<E> c){
    ...
}
```

As pointed out by Louis Wasserman I don't need the `Comparable` type cast.

Comment: I've just found that it works, I'd appreciate it if you showed me how to do it properly. I don't see where I'm not using generics.

Comment: I can't use `T` as it's not defined and using `E` gives `The method mergeSort(E[], Comparator<? super E>) in the type Sort is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable[], Comparator<E>)`, hence why I used the raw type before.

Comment: `T cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: If I don't use comparable I get `The method mergeSort(E[], Comparator<E>) in the type Sort is not applicable for the arguments (Object[], Comparator<E>)`

Comment: If I cast it to `E[]` then I get `The method mergeSort(E[], Comparator<E extends Comparable<E>>) in the type Sort is not applicable for the arguments (E[], Comparator<E>)`

Comment: Then how do I do it?

Comment: First of all we are lacking some informations here to give you proper help. The suppression of the warning is a big code smell - why do you need the casts at all?
Each cast could raise a ClassCastException, that's what the warning is for. You can prevent the warning by a preceding if with an instanceof operator - but what is your action, if the condition fails?
What type is the "internal class array" that you mentioned in your call to `.sort`? And if `sorter` is an instance of `Sort`, but that class declares a `mergeSort` method - how will that code ever compile?

Comment: The names of your sorting methods do not match, `sort` vs `mergeSort`. Further, your `ascComparator` is obsolete. Just use `if(c == null) c = (Comparator<? super E>)Comparator.naturalOrder();`

Answer (score 1):

Problem comes due to the `?` inside the `<? super E>` - two different `?` could be different types and are handled like that. You can see that from the message part "capture#8-of ?".

Also your mixing of raw types and unchecked casts will not help to solve your problem. In your code you have to casts to `Comparable` without the type parameter.

Comment: I've used `? super E` because that's what the docs for the `List` interface use. I'm not sure how to change my generics to avoid errors, because not using raw types causes a very similar error.